# Why only one $\infty $ point for each parallel class of lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, affine-geometry

I heard of projective geometry since high school. But I never managed to understand it in a systematic way.

It is said that the projective plane $\mathbb{P^2}(\mathbb{R})$ over the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ is obtained by adding to the ordinary plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ some infinity points.

The problem is, why just one $\infty $ point for each parallel class while for each line there are two ends?

Comment: In the projective plane, all the lines look the same.  Remove any line (call it the "line at infinity") and you get the affine plane.

Comment: You may (or may not) find my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200212/the-intersection-of-two-parallel-lines) helpful.

Answer (score 2):

One way to motivate this is: in the projective plane, any two distinct lines meet at exactly one point. This is a general instance of *homogeneity* - any two pairs of (distinct) lines in the projective plane "look alike" in an appropriate (specifically, *topological*) sense. If you added two points at infinity for every family of parallel lines, then parallel lines would behave differently than non-parallel lines.